# How can a file be configured to recognized as a certain language only in that session?

Tags: major-mode

I am editing a Drupal module file which doesn't use either a `.php` or `.module` extension.

How can I configure emacs to recognize the file alone as a PHP file:

1. regardless of the extension and
2. only for the session

If the file was the only file with that extension in the session how would I set the mode by the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I configure emacs to recognize the file alone as a PHP file:
>
> 1. regardless of the extension and
> 2. only for the session

As [major modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html) are just functions, you can enable any `major-mode`, whenever you like, in whichever buffer you like, by simply invoking its corresponding command. In your case, assuming the desired mode is called `php-mode`, you would invoke `M-x php-mode RET` in the buffer in question. There is usually nothing persistent about changing `major-mode` (unless a particular mode writes data to disk when enabled or similar), so the file would not automatically be detected as PHP the next time you read it.

> If the file was the only file with that extension in the session how would I set the mode by the extension?

This is normally achieved by modifying the variable `auto-mode-alist`, which maps filename patterns in the form of Elisp regular expressions to corresponding major modes. See the Emacs manual node on [Choosing Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html) and the variable's documentation (`C-h v auto-mode-alist RET` or `M-x describe-variable RET auto-mode-alist RET`) for more information.

For example, assuming the file's extension is `.drupal` and the desired `major-mode` is `php-mode`, you could write

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.drupal\\'" . php-mode))
```

Note that in Elisp, file extensions are usually terminated by the pattern `\'` instead of the more mainstream `$`. Emacs interprets the former as "end of string" and the latter as "end of line", so using the former avoids the theoretical possibility of failing to match a filename containing newlines. See the Emacs manual node on [Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) for more information on their usage and syntax.

Comment: I have tested the `M-x php-mode RET` and it works, but I also want to set it permanently for this file in particular. I have tried this method using `// -*- mode: php -*-` the file but it doesn't work. Have I got the syntax wrong? `//` is a valid PHP comment prefix.

Comment: @vfclists Nothing wrong with the syntax AFAICT. Is it on the first line in the file? Did you try rereading the file after adding the `mode` file-local variable? You can do this without killing the buffer via `M-x revert-buffer RET yes RET`. If you are not familiar with this command, I recommend you read its documentation (`C-h f revert-buffer RET` or `M-x describe-function RET revert-buffer RET`).

Comment: After putting it on the first line it works. Thanks

Comment: @vfclists Glad it worked. See the Emacs Manual node on [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) for more information on this.